# What is a good general reference on cognitive science in military training?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, cognitive-modeling, military-psychology

I know that one of the application of cognitive science is military science. Unfortunately I haven't found a good source on how cognitive science could benefit military training. Is there any comprehensive and simple source to read?

Comment: @Jeromy Anglim: thnks for good edition....

Comment: @Nick Stauner: thnks for edition...

Comment: Sure; thanks for the good question, and welcome to CogSci BTW!